# Stuck in arch loading screen

Tags: lazy-loading, arch, fsck

I been using arch for more than a month now. Today i was installing polybar by running the code:
sudo pacman -S polybar
I left it under process and went outside. When i came back i saw nothing but a stuck arch loading screen.

I am stuck in loading screen of arch.

Before this i got a message saying run fsck manually. I Tried this code:

fsck /dev/sda2

and give y to all permissions asked

But now i am stuck at screen that displays:

/dev/sda2: clean, 243786/1847776 files, 308153/7379456

I went to grub menu and removed the quite word, still no change.

After every reboot i am stucked at same screen of arch linux.

What should i do?